Xcode - Build input file cannot be found
After upgrading from Xcode 12, on any version of Xcode 13 or later, the following error occurs when running the sudo sh install-appledoc.sh command:
Build input file cannot be found: '~/<ProjectDir>/appledoc/default_templates.zip'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'appledoc' from project 'appledoc')
After researching the issue, the best lead I could find was to make sure that the target does not have any excluded architectures, which it does not. I can also confirm the noted file does exist at the stated location. So I am stumped on this one. Any ideas on how to fix please?

Search for "sandbox" in the target build settings; there is a setting relating to script sandboxing, but I don't recall its name.

@trojanfoe I checked it. It is called "User script sandboxing" and is set to NO, which I assume is correct?

Yes that's correct.  Next add some scripting to echo $HOME, before running that script (which I assume is a build phase script?).

@trojanfoe The bug appeared on our CI pipeline, so I thought I would run it locally on my machine and it caused the exact same bug. My scripting knowledge not that great so if you have any tips on how to echo $HOME I would appreciate it. Thanks for your help.

It's probably not the issue anyway. I think calling sudo within Xcode is probably a bad idea, and you might just be better off making the installation of stuff a pre-req before calling xcodebuild.

Maybe try using an absolute path instead of ~/ ... (eg. /Users/Username/...)

@l'L'l The absolute path is being used - I just redacted it for privacy purposes.

This can be fixed by adding $(PROJECT_DIR)/default_templates.zip to the Output Files section of the Build Phases of the Appledoc project.
